# How to access an attribute specified inside class scope, but not function scope in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, attributes

i want to assign the value `my_str` to a variable `my_out_of_scope_var2` that's defined inside a class `A`, but outside every method of that function. It feels pretty bad practice, but for the sake of a short question, let's assume i can not change the way it is implemented, because of legacy code.

```
class A:    
    def __init__(self, my_str):
        self.var1 = my_str
           
    def get_var1(self):
        return self.var1
    
    my_out_of_scope_var2 = ''

    # Ways NOT to do it
#     my_out_of_scope_var2 = bar             ----> not working, because bar is unknown here
#     my_out_of_scope_var2 = get_var1        ----> will assign the function >get_var1< to my_out_of_scope_var2
#     my_out_of_scope_var2 = self.var1       ----> does not work because self is unknown in this scope
#     my_out_of_scope_var2 = self.get_var1() ----> also does not work because self is unknown here
```

What i'm trying to achieve is this:

```
Foo = A('bar')
Foo.my_out_of_scope_var2
```

**and the output not being `''` but rather `'bar'`**.

How would i achieve that in a nice way in this kind of messy bad practice? I thought about using `__call__` or `__init__`, decorators like `@property` or functions, but i just can't get to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in `__init__` by referencing it through the class.

```
class A:    
    def __init__(self, my_str):
        self.var1 = my_str
        A.my_out_of_scope_var = my_str
      
    def get_var1(self):
        return self.var1
    
    my_out_of_scope_var2 = ''
```

Comment: Nice. Did not know until now that it is even possible to access the object we're creating at the very moment!

Comment: This works because the code inside `__init__` runs whenever you create a new `A` instance, but not when you create the `A` class itself